# Unable to retrieve value over a query object

Tags: python, django, apache

```
report_qs = CustomReport.objects.filter(id=report_id)

report_qs store below output
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "Locator__employer_state": "AR",
    "data_model_name": [
        "Locator",
        "PatientProfile"
    ]
}
```

Question: how to fetch all values and keys from above output in Python?

when i try to access key and values from above output i am getting following error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in **call**
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

Comment: According to `TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html`, you are trying to render an HTML file that does not exist in the template path. For this specific error, nothing is wrong about the code, you should locate your files correctly.

Comment: since i did overwrite error with template 500.html. i remove that file for getting trace stack nothing else..

Comment: Did you put your `500.html` somewhere else and forget to specify the location in the settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently getting all objects (by doing `all()`) and then you're bringing it back to one with `filter(id=report_id)`.

You can get all objects by only using `all()`:

```
report_qs = CustomReport.objects.all()
```

Comment: Hello Simeon, i need to access "Locator_employee_state value ",(data_model_name value ) ->"Locator" and "PatientProfile"

Answer (score 0):

It's a dictionary, so you can access its values with their respective key as below:

```
report_qs = CustomReport.objects.all().filter(id=report_id)

for res in report_qs:
    print res
    # Print Locator_employer_state
    print "Locator Employer State: " + str(res["Locator_employer_state"])
    # Print data_model_name_value
    string_ = ""
    for item in res["data_model_name"]: ### this loop is just for creating a nice string to print
        string_ += str(item) + ", "
    print "Data Model Name: " + string_
```

If you just want to access values, you can also use `.values()` method:

```
for res in report_qs:
    print str(res.values())
```

And just to cover all the ways, you can iterate over the dictionary using `.items()` methods:

```
for res in report_qs:
   for key, value in res.items():
       print str(key) + ": " + str(value)
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean by "requirement"? And what do you get instead?

Comment: i want to retrieve data_model_name (e.g. Locator,PatientProfile etc...) and Locator_employer_state with values "AR".

for fetching values i wrote code ( report_qs['data_model_name'][0] )

 result should be "Locator" but instead of that i am getting.. "Nothing" (TypeError: string indices must be integers)

Comment: i am using below written code for insertion...

    data = serializers.serialize('json',
                                 YourModel.objects.filter(id=id),
                                 fields=('list','of','fields'))
    
    
    report_qs = CustomReport.objects.all().filter(id=report_id)
    
    
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
    
    how to get all values in djanog

Comment: I think I got it; `report_qs` is a list of dictionaries. You should first iterate over the list using index and then iterate over the dictionary using the key. I mean you should write `report_qs[0]['data_model_name']`. But it returns `["Locator", "PatientProfile"]`; if you just want to receive `"Locator"`, you should write `report_qs[0]['data_model_name'][0]`.